# Microsoft garph api sendActivityNotification contentType html error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

when we use content type text it is working fine but when i make it to html i have an error
i have to format the text to italics

this is the error i am facing:

**Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest Message: Content Type 'Html' is not supported.**

Comment: Could you please share the API docs that you are following along with your request data?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

the payload is of type itemBody, link to item body
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itembody?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @umgolla - As mentioned in following document the the content type text and html are allowed for PreviewText only.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body

Comment: yes to that only we are adding of type html
` var previewText = new ItemBody
   {
     Content = activityFeedRequest.PreviewText,
     ContentType = BodyType.Html
 }`

Comment: @umgolla - We are able to repro this issue and we have raised a bug for it.
We will let you know once we get updates on it.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, any updates on this

Comment: @umgolla - We have informed Engineering team about the same and they are currently working on the fix. We will inform you once we have further update.

Answer (score 0):

**This is by design**

ContentType html is for the itemBody generally as a schema element. For this API it doesnt take all the values.

Ref Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-sendactivitynotification?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http